# OOD in C# - Determine Which Properties are Inherited vs which are Declared in Current Class

Tags: c#, json

Consider the following example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string StringInBaseClass {get;set;}
    public int IntInBaseClass {get;set;}
}

public InheritingClass : BaseClass
{
     public long LongInInheritingClass {get;set;}
     public long ShortInInheritingClass {get;set;}
     public long CharInInheritingClass {get;set;}
}
```

Now, what I want to do is serialize JUST the inheriting properties to a JSON string.  For example, I want to somehow create a JSON object out of just the 3 properties in InheritingClass, but if I do:

```
InheritingClass a = new InheritingClass();
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
string jsonString = jss.Serialize(a);
```

The **jsonString** value will have all of the properties of the BaseClass as well as all of the properties of InheritingClass.  I understand that is normal, because I am inheriting all of those properties.  What I am looking to do is NOT include those inherited properties and build a JSON string out of ONLY the 3 properties in InheritingClass.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Sounds more like a serialization issue than an object oriented design and polymorphism issue. Suggest working out how to disable serialization on the `BaseClass`' properties.

Comment: That smells very much like a flaw in your inheritance. If at sometimes you only want part of the object it becomes difficult to argue that an is-a relation exists it sound a lot more like has-a aka composition

Comment: You're right, it is a serialization issue, rather than ODD.

Comment: @Oded ... I am building a messaging class that sends JSON over http from a server to various clients (JavaScript).  I am building a "Core" message (BaseClass in this case) that has the properties for EVERY message type, then implementing various message types for the specific messages (InheritingClass in this case).  I basically need a way to pull out the specific message fields independently from the Core message properties without hard coding field names.  I want to let the JavaScript JSON serializer build the objects for me on the client.

Comment: Also don't forget, there is something weird about the way the JavaScriptSerializer serializes DateTime.

Comment: @Yuriy Thanks for the heads up!  I will be on the look-out for that.

Comment: @Rune FS - I really only want to ignore those properties for serialization purposes, not altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ScriptIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) on any property you don't want serialized with the JavaScriptSerializer. With this you can do the following in your inherited class to stop a property from the base class from being serialized:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string StringInBaseClass {get;set;}
    public int IntInBaseClass {get;set;}
}

public class InheritingClass : BaseClass
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public override string StringInBaseClass
    {
        get
        {
            return base.StringInBaseClass;
        }
        set
        {
            base.StringInBaseClass = value;
        }
    }
    public long LongInInheritingClass {get;set;}
    public long ShortInInheritingClass {get;set;}
    public long CharInInheritingClass {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *never* want to serialize those properties (even when serializing the base class or other derived classes) you can add the ScriptIgnore attribute to the base class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public string StringInBaseClass {get;set;}
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public int IntInBaseClass {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code return properties(type of PropertyInfo[]) that inherited members are not considered:

```
typeof(InheritingClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuri is correct in how to get json to ignore the property.

However, there is no way to implicity ignore the properties of the base class, the inheriting class **is** the base class, that's how inheritance works.

Comment: Yeah I understand that.  I wasn't trying to NOT inherit the properties, I was just trying to identify which properties were inherited VS which were declared in the inheriting class.